# how to set iOS 6/7 Deltas programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, xcode5, delta

I was developing a UISplitView app by using Xcode 4.6 when I left iOS6 I had design:

[image]

Now I migrate to new Xcode5 and now I have this design:

[image]

UINavigationBar overlaps completelly my UISearchBar...

Leo Natan told me about using a iOS 6/7 Deltas but since I'm creating and adding my UISplitViewControllers programmatically,

this may doesn't work I need to set the iOS 6/7 programmatically but I don't know how, any help I'll appreciate

Comment: If you want to do this in code, you have to work with frames. `if (iOS7) {view.frame = ...} else {view.frame = ...}`

Comment: @PetroKorienev Or just change constraint constants? It's easier than to update frames.

Comment: The OP doesn't use auto-layout, and initialized his controllers in code. Adding constraints in code isn't way easier than updating frames..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In iOS 7 there are now extended edges, and that's why navigation bar overlaping the searchbar. You can set `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` this is UIVewControlelr property.
You can also make checks depending on version of iOS and You can do things depending on current version of iOS in device.

```
NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
int ver = [version intValue];
if (ver < 7){
//iOS 6 work
}
else{
//iOS 7 related work
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can use NSFoundationVersionNumber

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
  // > iOS7
} else {
  // <= iOS6
}
```

Comment: This way is suggested by Apple in iOS 7 transition guide.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a makro for solve this problem.
it is useful for me.

```
#define iOS7Delta (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0 ) ? 20 : 0 )
```

Answer (score -2):

If the view's embedded in a UINavigationController -
simply untick "Translucent" for your root navigation bar.

*In storyboard, select Navigation Controller Scene, 
next select Navigation Bar and in Attributes Inspector (Utilities - 4 tab)
untick "Translucent"*